# Intervening threads that waited for too long

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, f#

Is there anyway in F# that I can detect if a current waiting thread is waiting for too long without being contacted?

I have a case where threads must be actively contacting other waiting threads to pass their work to once they're finished. My solution is having a bug somewhere that sometimes one or more threads just wait for too long and eventually the program got deadlocked because other threads don't contact them.

I think by detecting if a waiting thread is simply waiting for too long, it will just actively go looking for available work, rather than keeping waiting for other threads to pass to it.

Comment: Depends on how you're waiting, but usually, the waiting function has some sort of timeout that you could set. See e.g.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to try and understand why your threads are getting stuck than just terminating them. If you can reproduce this with the Visual Studio debugger attached, you can click the Pause button and use the Threads window to see what code all threads are in.

That said; if you still have the need to do this, the solution will depend on how you're managing your threads. To monitor them from the outside, you'll need some process that has a list of threads and the ability to tell whether they're dead.

The `Thread` class doesn't appear have any built-in mechanism for sharing state between the thread and its control except for `Name`. You could possibly abuse name, but I would probably have a thread-safe collection (eg. a [`ConcurrentDictionary<Thread, DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)) to store all of the threads and the timestamp of their last communication, and pass an `Action` into each thread when it's started that allows it to "`Ping`" by calling the action periodically. The action would simply update the `DateTime` stored against that thread.

The controlling process then simply scans through the dictionary periodically for anything with a timestamp that is too old, declares that thread dead and `Aborts()` it.

It's hard to give a code sample without knowing exactly how you're spawning your threads and describe what a thread "being contacted" means in more detail.